# What happens to someone who wraps tefillin before the earliest time to wrap tefillin?

Tags: halacha, time, tefilin, zemanim

What happens to someone who finishes wrapping tefillin before the earliest official time?

Does he still gets the mitzvah?

Is there any way he can get around the earliest time?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.30.3?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.30&lang2=bi